# I have a div input element as it is from ajax response and i want to focus that element when my form is ready

Tags: javascript

the below is the code and it looks like a text box when it is seen in the GUI and  i want to focus  this 
div when my document is loaded and i have tried with the focus its not working

```
   <div 
    contenteditable="true" required="false" type="text"
    onkeyup="javascript:ObjmessageSystem.validatetext(this);" 
    onfocus="callOnFocus(this);ObjmessageSystem.setCurrentMessageFieldObject(this)"
    onkeypress="return noSpecialCharactersCheck(event,'-1');"
    istimesavingshortkeyapplicable="true"
    class="input_field width_3"
    id="38be576c-4ca4-4510-b84d-02db4e3bd1f0"
    name="38be576c-4ca4-4510-b84d-02db4e3bd1f0"
    fieldtitle="Name" optiontype="textbox" outputorder="0"
    onblur="removeCallOnFocus()" tabindex="1">
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as below in jQuery

```
$.get(youUrlHere, {param:paramValue}, function (data) {
    $('div').focus();
});
```

For simple HTTP Request use:

```
function doFocus () {
    document.getElementByTagName('div').focus();
}

var Req = new XMLHttpRequest();
Req.onload = doFocus;
Req.open("get", yourUrl, true);
Req.send();
```